# Linq to Entities: .Clear() does not delete relation row, only relation column value

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

I have a 'users' and 'notifications' tables.
The tables definition are:

```
users        notifications
-------      -------------
ID (PK)      ID (PK)
Name         Name
             users_ID (FK / Relation)
```

When I do:

```
MyUserEntity.notifications.clear();
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

The users_ID column value(s) for the corresponding user entity are set to NULL, but I want the rows to be deleted.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(var notification in MyUserEntity.notifications.ToList())
{
    MyContext.DeleteObject(notification);
}
MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I get `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.` on the `foreach` line.

Comment: Try `(var notification in MyUserEntity.notifications.ToList())`